# Scala mutable.BitSet intersection performance

Tags: performance, scala, bitset

I am trying to write a backtracking algorithm that keeps state using mutable BitSets, it works fine but I want it to go faster!

The crux is given two mutable.BitSet alpha and beta I need to calculate if any of the bits of alpha are set in beta, i.e. bitwise AND.  I do not need the resulting set just need to know if the intersection isNonEmpty

```
(alpha intersect beta).nonEmpty
```

or

```
(alpha & beta).nonEmpty
```

but both of these construct a set which is then tested for size... I really just need a boolean and would like to avoid the cost of constructing the intermediate set.

Is there a better way?

TIA
Nivag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to the [API docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.BitSet), you may use `find` and `contains` method.

```
alpha find (beta.contains) isDefined
```

**OR**

Even better, use `exists` method.

```
alpha exists (beta.contains)
```

**OR**

Even shorter and better, use `apply` method of [BitSet](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.BitSet) which is equivalent to its  `contains` method.

```
alpha exists beta
```